# How to prove a function is surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Question

Let  = {| ∈ ℝ   ≥ 1} and  = {| ∈ ℝ  0 <  ≤ 1}.

$f(x)= (1/2)^x + 1/2$

I need to prove this function is an onto function

> Attempts

I assume $y ∈ T$  and let $x= \log_\frac 12 (y-\frac 12)$ and I can have the result $f(x)=y$ and this means it is surjective because for every $y ∈ T$ there exists $x ∈ S$ and $f(x) = y$.

However, the domain of $(y-\frac 12)$ is $-\frac 12< (y-\frac 12)≤ \frac 12$ and there is a contradiction that $(y-\frac 12)$ must greater than 0. In this situation, is my proof still correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  Your argument appears to imagine that $f$ is a function from $S$ to $T$ though you don't say this anywhere.  As such, it is clearly not surjective (for the reason you mention.  Are you quite sure you didn't mean to consider $f$ as a function from $T$ to $S$?

Comment: No, f is a function from S to T. So, this function in this case is not onto?@lulu

Comment: $f(x)>\frac 1  2$ for all $x \in S$, so $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: It is not onto.  Indeed, $\left(\frac 12\right)^x$ is strictly positive so $f(x)>\frac 12$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{1}{2}\right]^x \geq 0.$  Therefore, for all $ ~x~$ such that $~x \geq 1,~$ you have that $~f(x) \geq \dfrac{1}{2}.~$  Therefore, for all $~y~$ such that $0 < y < \dfrac{1}{2},~$ you have that $~y~$  is **not** in the range of $~f(x).$

Comment: ok ok, the original question is Let  = {| ∈ ℝ   ≥ 1} and  = {| ∈ ℝ  0 <  ≤ 1}.Find a function :  →  that is a bijection. It seems I found the wrong function.

Comment: Please put the original question in the body of your question.

Comment: ok@AdamRubinson

Comment: Since there are a lot of comments (and a, now deleted, solution) concerning the question as first posed, I suggest posting a new question with the intended version.  The intended version is, after all, *very* different from what you actually posted.

Comment: ok, I will a post a new one @lulu

Comment: a function that is bijective from $(0,1]$ to $[1,\infty)$ is $f(x)=1/x$